# My PC will not shut off if monitors are turned off

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, motherboard, shutdown

Whenever I try to shut down my PC I typically shut off the monitors at the same time and they're usually off before the PC is. I recently changed some hardware including my motherboard (ASROCK B650 PG Lightning), CPU (AMD Ryzen 5 7600X) and graphics card (ASROCK AMD Radeon RX 6600 Challenger 8G), and since then I've been having the issue that my PC will not shut down; some lights remain on, and sometimes it will even beep five times, seemingly indicating a problem with the GPU. I have to shut off my PC by holding the power button.

However, when I once for some reason didn't shut off the monitors when shutting down my PC, I noticed that there wasn't any issue at all and it shut down fine. I've since experimented a bit and can say with certainty now that allowing the monitors to stay on during shutdown prevents the issue.

What's going wrong here and how can I get my PC to shut down normally under all circumstances?

Comment: It might be trying to display an error message and pausing the shutdown?

Comment: Have you tried shutting from command line, e.g., make a shortcut to `shutdown /s /t 0`, or even `shutdown /s /f /t 0` to *force* shutdown. You could also check error logs for issue.